# Disable nicescroll when class added

Tags: jquery, nicescroll

I wonder if it's possible to disable scrolling when there is a class added to the body?
The body get a class when i trigger a button already but still can't disable scrolling when that happened. I have tried everything in js and css but can't get it done with nicescroll.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").niceScroll(); {
        horizrailenabled: false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in css:

```
body.noScroll {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Yes. 
the problem that nicescroll plugin forcing its scrolling